# Group Lists into one folder

Tags: list

I have several Lists created (`Action Items, Decisions made, Risk Log, Issue Log etc`). I need to create one folder called **RAID Tool** and want to group all the above lists under this and create a shortcut for viewers to see these lists. How to create this"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't place list inside list. What you should have done is

1. Create content types for "Action Items", "Decisions Made", "Risk Log", "Issue Log"
2. Create cusomt list "RAID Tool"
3. Add those content types to the list

The above suggestion is valid only in case those are related.

I believe what you really for is to have a central place from where users can move the respective list. For that

1. Create a new page
2. Add content editor webpart
3. Add URL (hyperlinks) to the various lists as below

   ```
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <h2>RAID Tools</h2>
           </td>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <a href="/lists/action items">Action Items</a>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <a href="/lists/decisions made">Decisions Made</a>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <a href="/lists/risk log">Risk Log</a>
           </td>
       </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>
               <a href="/lists/issue log">Issue Log</a>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```